# React Intersection Observe, get lot of request in API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have an intersection observe in my UsseEffect and when isIntersecting is true a have a lot of request and i get this errors
Access to XMLHttpRequest at
GET(url)net::ERR_FAILED 503
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
how can nake a good intersection?

my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-varahamihira-cw6p6?file=/src/App.js

PD. my loader is always there inclusive when i dont have more cards to show
please somebody explain me

Comment: You are running into recursion here: your useEffect hook runs whenever `cards` is updated, and yet in the same hook you are updating `cards`.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening can you explain me please?

Comment: Your `useEffect()` is listening to `cards` as a dependency: it will run every time `cards` is updated. Yet in the same function you are **updating** `cards`. so you end up in an infinite loop.